# Return 2 variable in -(CGFloat)

Tags: objective-c

I want return 2 arguments in my method `-(CGFloat)`. I try many way but can't. Here is my code. I want return both of them "heightSpace" and "widthSpace".

```
-(CGFloat) spaceBetweenLedCenterWhenNumberLedIsKnown: (int) n andM: (int) m {
    CGFloat heightSpace = (self.view.bounds.size.height - 2 * _heightMargin) / (n - 1);
    CGFloat widthSpace = (self.view.bounds.size.width - 2 * _widtheMargin) / (m - 1);

    return [self spaceBetweenLedCenterWhenNumberLedIsKnown:heightSpace andM:widthSpace];
}
```

I have solve my problems with CGSize. Here is my final code. Thank to Zaph.

```
-(CGSize) coutingSpaceBetweenLedInHeight: (int) height andWidth: (int) width {

CGFloat heightSpace = (self.view.bounds.size.height - 2 * _heightMargin) / (height - 1);

CGFloat widthSpace = (self.view.bounds.size.width - 2 * _widthMargin) / (width - 1);

//typedef struct CGSize CGSize;

return CGSizeMake(heightSpace, widthSpace);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Return a `CGSize`, that contains two `CGFloats` named `width` and `height`.

The caller can easily obtain the two values.

```
struct CGSize { CGFloat width; CGFloat height; }; typedef struct CGSize CGSize;
```